# Perl Parallel::ForkManager , takes long time with fork condition changed

Tags: perl, dictionary, fork

I have two questions with Parallel::ForkManager , in modifing the pid condition.

Question 1 : with a simple example,

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Parallel::ForkManager;
use IO::Socket ;

my $np = 32 ;
my $pm = Parallel::ForkManager->new($np);
$| = 1 ;

sub do_something{ #an example for 3 second delay
    my $port = shift @_ ;
    my $tgt = 192.168.0.1 ;
    my $sock = IO::Socket::INET->new(PeerAddr=>"$tgt:$port",Proto='tcp',Timeout=>3) ;
    $sock ? return $sock : return 0 ;
}

foreach (1..64) {
    $pm->start and next ;
    do_something($_) ;
    $pm->finish ;
}
$pm->wait_all_children ;
```

The above script works , with

```
time perl simple_script.pl 

real    0m7.109s
user    0m0.237s
sys     0m0.080s
```

while modifying the

```
$pm->start and next ; 
do_something($_) ;
```

to

```
$pm->start and next or do_something($_) ;
```

or

```
!($pm->start) or do_something($_) ;
```

does seem to work also but not as intended.

```
time perl modified_script.pl 

real     3m12.307s
user     0m0.237s
sys      0m0.080s
```

seems like the other two modified version run a single process at a time.

Question 2:

Is there any alternate way to do the same without using the next inside the foreach loop? That way the script can be adapted for map instead of a foreach loop.

P.S: Forking and Object creation are not my strong points.

Edit: removed & as per suggestion .

Comment: The big question is why you want to use a `map`, which is intended for translating one list to another by applying the same function to each element of the input list. By the way, don't use an ampersand `&` when calling Perl functions: that hasn't been necessary since Perl 4 about twenty years ago

Answer (score 0):

If you change this loop

```
foreach (1..64) {
  $pm->start and next;
  do_something($_);
  $pm->finish;
}
```

to this

```
foreach (1..64) {
  !($pm->start) or do_something($_);
}
```

then you have removed the `$pm->finish` call which terminates each child. That means the child processes will continue to execute the `for` loop, trying to start their own children, which will fail (because the child processes need their own `Parallel::ForkManager` object - they cannot use the parent's) and so they will `do_something` each time around the loop. Furthermore, because the children are delayed while they execute the subroutine many times, it will take much longer to get all 64 children started because you have a limit of 32 running at any one time.

You could write

```
for ( 1 .. 64 ) {
  my $pid = $pm->start;
  if ( $pid == 0 ) {
    do_something($_);
    $pm->finish;
  }
}

$pm->wait_all_children;
```

but as I said in my comment, if this is just so that you can misuse `map` instead of using a `for` then please don't do it

Comment: Thanks for the respone, but i did not remove the $pm->finish ; my code was !($pm->start) or do_something($_) ; $pm->finish; But now i understand where the logic went wrong. $pm->finish is executed irrespective of do_something($_) was performed.

Comment: @vagrant: I hope you will explain why you want to use `map` please?

Comment: I will try to be brief, I was trying to use perl as a wrapup script.  basically i have some function in fortran (and some C written) which does some quadrature integrations and matrix operations, on a set of matrices. These matrices are generated from varying a single parameter and hence It was easy to think of the range of the parameter as a list and the series of operations acting on the list. Passing the operations as map piping seemed logical at that point.  so thought it would be good to use fork with a map - probably not!.

Answer (score 0):

The changes you claimed you made would not cause the process to take longer. As such, I'm going to concentrate on your question: How to convert foreach loop into a `map` loop.

`for (LIST) BLOCK` can be written as `map BLOCK LIST`. The catch is that you can't use `next` since each pass of the loop is expected to return something (if only the empty list).

```
my $pm = ...;
map {
   if (!$pm->start) {
      do_something($_);
      $pm->finish;
   }
   ()
} 1..64;
$pm->wait_all_children();
```

or

```
sub child {
   my ($job) = @_;
   ...
   exit();
}

{
   my $pm = ...;
   map { $pm->start or child($_) } 1..64;
   $pm->wait_all_children();
}
```

I have no idea why you'd want to do that. It just makes the code harder to read.